# Erlang: Shortest way to check if two values are zero?

Tags: erlang

I'm creating a function that takes `X` and `Y` as arguments, and returns `false` if either `X` is 0, `Y` is 0, or `X` and `Y` are both 0. I'm currently using a case statement, but I was wondering if it's possible to write this function shorter (e.g. merge the two 'false' cases into one case).

```
validate_input(X, Y) ->
    case {X, Y} of
        {0, _} -> false;
        {_, 0} -> false;
        _      -> true
    end.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `andalso`:

```
validate_input(X, Y) ->
    X =/= 0 andalso Y =/= 0.
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised, nay, *shocked* that simply matching in the function head hasn't been recommended yet:

```
validate_input(0, _) -> true;
validate_input(_, 0) -> true;
validate_input(_, _) -> false.
```

"Tight" code isn't about reducing line counts, it is about reducing the number of concepts you have to recall to interpret a given piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (though I'd prefer legoscia's) is using `if`:

```
validate_input(X, Y) ->
  if
    X == 0; Y == 0 -> false;
    true -> true
  end.
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching, I also found this solution:

```
validate_input(X, Y) ->
    case {X, Y} of
        {X, Y} when X == 0; Y == 0 -> false;
        _      -> true
    end.
```

Or even more efficient, as legoscia suggested:

```
validate_input(X, Y) when X == 0; Y == 0 -> false;
validate_input(_,_) -> true.
```

Comment: You could put the guard directly on the function head: `validate_input(X, Y) when X == 0; Y == 0 -> false;
validate_input(_,_) -> true.`